# running phantomjs on a page that is opened with casperjs

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

Now i have two parts of programs 
lets say 'a' for a casperjs prog and 'b' for a phantomjs prog

and i am trying to pass the page which is opened by 'a' then pass the page to 'b'

i know that both have 'page' object.
but i have no idea how to use the 'page' object in casperjs... or is there any way to run a phantomjs prog after openning a page in casperjs....?

in the phantomjs prog, i want to make use of this so if i can pass the page to the phantomjs in page/content object would be the best

```
var webPage = require('webpage')
var page = webPage.create()
var content = page.content
```

Comment: PhantomJS runs under the hood of CasperJS. Do you have some legacy code or what do you want to achieve? You can access the underlying page from CasperJS code: `casper.page`. CasperJS has also access to the content by `casper.getHTML` or `casper.getPageContent`

Comment: @ArtjomB. i really have some problems with my eyes... how could i miss that in the doc..... thanks a lo!!!!!